# I cannot make a POST request to /questions/ID/answers 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

so I am making an API for creating questions and getting answers on the question id but whenever I use postman to create a POST request to answers.

Whenever I create a POST request to **http://localhost:3000/api/questions/ID/answers** it gives me a 404. I use node-restful package for creating this API and here is the Schema

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
// Database
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Question Schema
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  qTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  qBody: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date
  },
  answers: [{
    aTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    aBody: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
  }]
});


// Export the question schema
module.exports = restful.model('Questions', QuestionSchema);
```

If there is any errors or if you wish to see more code let me know!

Here is my routes

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var Question = require('../models/question');

Question.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Question.register(router, '/questions');


// Exports the router
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Also, I am aware that 404 means it cannot be found but I would think I could make a POST request with the /questions/ID/answers and still inject the json data I setup in postman to the specific question I used.

Comment: can you also paste your routes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  add `:id/answers` like

```
Question.register(router, '/questions/:id/answers');
```

Comment: That did something but now it's validation error with qTitle & qBody

Comment: I removed the required tags and now it just creates new empty questions with the answers not in them. Strange

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for node-restful you need to turn on detail: true in a custom route like:

```
Question.route('answers', {
method:'post',
detail: true,
handler: function(req, res, next) {
    // req.params.id holds the resource's id
    res.send("I'm at /questions/:id/answers")
}
```

});

this is totally untested, and likely not completely correct since your model is complex and all the examples were pretty simple. But you definitely need a custom route. This little code snippet probably will set up a bunch of routes you don't want as well, but it should point you in the right direction.

I just took a quick look at the documentation here:
http://www.baugarten.me/node-restful/